# Enable es6 template string support in php/webStorm

Tags: phpstorm, ecmascript-6

I experience some issues with es6's template strings in Phpstorm and am wondering if there's a setting to enable support for those.

[image]

it seems like phpstorm doesn't recognize template strings correctly. The file as I have it here works without problems, but using template strings completely breaks syntax highlighting and everything else.

Is there a way to make phpstorm recognize them, or is it a bug I should report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WEB-17557](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17557) is fixed in WebStorm 11/PHPStorm 9.5

Comment: Do you know when 9.5 will be released?

Comment: It can be expected early in November